# Java - Rounding 99999999999999.9999

Tags: java, rounding

I am trying rounding and format techniques in Java as I have to keep my values in database with some specific formats.

My database column has the data precision of 18,4 which means 14 integers and 4 decimal places at max.

Now I am trying max possible value case which is 99999999999999.9999. When I execute the below code, I am getting a rounded value of 1000000000000000. However, I want to store the exact value provided.

Can anyone suggest to keep it as it is in java variable?

```
    DecimalFormat df2 = new DecimalFormat( "#.####" );
    df2.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.CEILING);
    double number = Double.parseDouble("99999999999999.9999");
    System.out.println("Format: " + df2.format(number));
```

Comment: `precision of 18,2 which means 14 integers and 4 decimal places` that's not possible with double which has precision of only 53 bits ~15 digits

Comment: any other option?

Comment: Shouldn't the precision of your database column be 18,4? If you want 4 decimal places

Comment: Doesn't 18,2 mean one sign,  15 integers and 2 decimal places?

Comment: Sorry, it was my typo, thats 18,4 which means 14 integral values and 4 decimal parts.

Comment: If you want decimal math, use a decimal number type (`BigDecimal`) instead of a binary number type.

Comment: You're losing information on this statement, `double number = Double.parseDouble("99999999999999.9999");` you cannot use a `double`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use BigDecimal

```
BigDecimal number = new BigDecimal("99999999999999.9999");
```